# Confidence Bound of linear regression using polyfit and polyconf

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval

I am doing a simple linear regression  and I am trying to plot the 95% confidence boundary using the matlab functions polyfit and polyconf, but I'm wondering why I am getting more than two lines for the boundary? Thank you for your help.

```
x1= [ 165.371 227.7475 204.4437 93.874 259.2976 113.3138 74.67 121.1493 60.7095 46.7491  355.6146  876.4135  1.2875  169.7753  341.4739   29.8034   260.1231  664.0960 ];

y= [ 165.371 228.6 203.416 93.874 262.066 104.902 74.67 121.63 59.463 46.749061 186.82666 931.3108984074 11.287521 176.76547  338.75586  29.803396 169.38878 692.66666  ];

surface_area_model = fitlm(y,x1,'linear')

[p,s]=polyfit(y,x1,1);
[yfit,dy]=polyconf(p,y,s,'predopt','curve');
figure(3)
a= 100;
h1= scatter(y,x1,a,'ob','LineWidth',1.2);

line(y,yfit,'color','b','LineWidth',2);
line(y,yfit-dy,'color','r','linestyle',':');
line(y,yfit+dy,'color','r','linestyle',':');
```

Figure:

[image: Linear Regression with Confidence Boundaries]

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not sorted in ascending order. In fact not only the boundary, but the data and fitted data line are of multiple segments as well.

Applying the following code which sorts the data right after assignments

```
[y,k] = sort(y);
x1 = x1(k);
```

will result in this graph

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Thanks.Very helpful.